# ManagerId is not assigning for inactive user using apex trigger?

Tags: apex, after-trigger

My Trigger Scenario:

/       ' .  -  ()  -  ( ).

I have created ManagerId__c as a custom field on the Account object.

**My implementation:**

trigger userTrigger on User (after update) {

```
Switch on Trigger.OperationType
{
    when AFTER_UPDATE
    {
        
       userHandler.checkUser(Trigger.new,Trigger.oldMap);
            
        
    }
    
    
}
```

}

**Handler class:**

public class userHandler {

```
public static void checkUser(List<User> userList,Map<Id,User> mapoldUser)
{
    Set<Id> deactivateuserIds=new Set<Id>();
    
    for(User u:userList)
    {
        if(mapoldUser.get(u.Id).isActive==true && u.IsActive==false)
        {
            deactivateuserIds.add(u.Id);
            
        }
        
        
    }
    
    assignUserManager(deactivateuserIds);
   
    
}

@future
public static void assignUserManager(Set<Id> userIds)
{
    if(!userIds.isEmpty())
    {
        List<Account> accToUpdate=new List<Account>();
        List<Account> userAccounts=new List<Account>();
        
        Map<Id,Id> managerMap=new Map<Id,Id>();
        
        
        for(User u:[Select Id,Name,ManagerId from User where Id in:userIds])
        {
            managerMap.put(u.Id,u.ManagerId);
            
            
        }
        
        userAccounts=[Select Id,OwnerId from Account where OwnerId in:managerMap.keySet()];
        if(!userAccounts.isEmpty())
        {
            
            for(Account acc:userAccounts)
            {
                Id managerId=managerMap.get(acc.OwnerId);
                if(managerId!=null && acc.OwnerId!=null)
                {
                    acc.OwnerId=managerId;
                    accToUpdate.add(acc);
                }
                
            }
            
            
        }
        
        
        if(!accToUpdate.isEmpty())
        {
            update accToUpdate;
            
            
        }
        
        
    }
    
    
}
```

}

I have refactored my code from my previous one. For example, I have a user called Steve and his manager is John if i deactivate Steve then his manager John will not update as a manager on the owner account field and resulting in null values so what could be the workaround to do? Are there any mistakes that I have made?

Comment: While your trigger should ideally just be calling your handler (finding the inactive users ought to be done in your handler, and that would help you get rid of the query on `User` in your handler), that' shouldn't be the source of the issue. You should add a debug statement to see if your `userIds` set is empty. You should also check your debug log to see if the user query is returning any rows. Either of those things would cause the Account query to return no rows.

Comment: ok i will check it.