# Manager Id is not updating whenver the user is deactivated using apex trigger

Tags: trigger, future, after-trigger, after

**My implementation:**

```
trigger userTrigger on User (after update) {
    
    Switch on Trigger.OperationType
    {
        when AFTER_UPDATE
        {
            
           userHandler.checkUser(Trigger.new,Trigger.oldMap);
                
            
        }
        
        
    }

}
```

**Handler class:**

```
public class userHandler {
    
    public static void checkUser(List<User> userList,Map<Id,User> mapoldUser)
    {
        Set<Id> deactivateuserIds=new Set<Id>();
        
        for(User u:userList)
        {
            if(mapoldUser.get(u.Id).isActive==true && u.IsActive==false)
            {
                deactivateuserIds.add(u.Id);
                
            }
            
            
        }
        
        assignUserManager(deactivateuserIds);
       
        
    }
    
    @future
    public static void assignUserManager(Set<Id> userIds)
    {
        if(!userIds.isEmpty())
        {
            List<Account> accToUpdate=new List<Account>();
            List<Account> userAccounts=new List<Account>();
            
            Map<Id,Id> managerMap=new Map<Id,Id>();
            
            
            for(User u:[Select Id,Name,ManagerId from User where Id in:userIds])
            {
                managerMap.put(u.Id,u.ManagerId);
                
                
            }
            
            userAccounts=[Select Id,OwnerId from Account where OwnerId in:managerMap.keySet()];
            if(!userAccounts.isEmpty())
            {
                
                for(Account acc:userAccounts)
                {
                    Id managerId=managerMap.get(acc.OwnerId);
                    if(managerId!=null)
                    {
                        acc.OwnerId=managerId;
                        accToUpdate.add(acc);
                    }
                    
                }
                
                
            }
            
            
            if(!accToUpdate.isEmpty())
            {
                update accToUpdate;
                
                
            }
            
            
        }
        
        
    }
}
```

For example, I have an user called james and manager name(Id) is steve so my question is if i deactivate the user james then the manager
steve is not updating on account ownerId field. When i checked with debug log, I found an issue with this account foor loop.

**Here is my code below:**

```
userAccounts=[Select Id,OwnerId from Account where OwnerId in:managerMap.keySet()];

if(!userAccounts.isEmpty())
{
                
    for(Account acc:userAccounts)
    {
       Id managerId=managerMap.get(acc.OwnerId);
       if(managerId!=null)
       {
            acc.OwnerId=managerId;
            accToUpdate.add(acc);
       }
                    
     }
                 
}
```

The user ID is not being retrieved correctly inside the for loop, resulting in a null value. What could be the workaround for this issue?

Comment: This is a duplicate of your previous question [ManagerId is not assigning for inactive user using apex trigger?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/417147/managerid-is-not-assigning-for-inactive-user-using-apex-trigger). Please don't create duplicates. Continue using your previous question (you can edit it to add these details).